# Is there a dynamic light-amount dependent material change node setup?

Tags: materials, node-editor, light, lighting, shadows

I have a mountain scene and I want to reduce snow only from the bright areas of a plane.
Is there a way to do this dynamically, so I dont have to use vertex paint, and it reacts to light change?
Like is there a node setup that detects light amount or something like this?

Comment: Nice question.. could we ask you for some specs? Do you want the snow to have thickness? If so, would you be prepared to bake an image sequence to control it? (That would need a separate pass).. and do you want the snow to _stay_ melted, even if the light has come off it?

Comment: My only goal it to simply make the snow disappear where the sun shines and I'm not planning on animation this time. 
But if keeping the snow melted is possible, it would be nice to know for later.

Comment: In EEVEE, there's a _Shader to RGB_ node, which lets you do anything you like with the light-response of a surface, but no displacement, so for thickness, you would need a bake.. there are other routes..